# How to UPDATE an Access Date/Time field with the current date

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I'm using the following code to update a *datetime* field in a linked SQL table with the current date and time. However, the date that get's entered is 12/29/1899. I don't understand what I'm missing here. Any ideas?

`CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE dbo_PAYMENT SET PAYMENT_CC_DATE_PROCESSED=#" & Now & "# AND PAYMENT_CC_EMPLOYEE_ID = 0 WHERE PAYMENT_ID=" & Me.PAYMENT_ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is it! Thanks so much @Gord Thompson!

> @mntyguy Aha, I see the syntax error. If you want to update multiple fields you need to use SET Field1=value1, Field2=value2, not SET Field1=value1 AND Field2=value2

Answer (score 4):

If you use Access SQL's built-in `Now()` function then you don't need to put hash marks (`#`) around it. (They are only required to delimit a date *literal*, not a date *function*.) Try

```
... SET PAYMENT_CC_DATE_PROCESSED=Now() ...
```

or, if the time component is not needed you can use

```
... SET PAYMENT_CC_DATE_PROCESSED=Date() ...
```

Also, if you want to update multiple fields you need to use

```
... SET Field1=value1, Field2=value2 ...
```

not

```
... SET Field1=value1 AND Field2=value2 ...
```

Comment: Didn't work. It gave me a syntax error. I don't understand what could be wrong here. I've used this function in other places and it has worked no problem. :/

Comment: @mntyguy I just tried it against a `datetime` column in SQL Server 2008 R2 and it worked fine for me. Try deleting the table link and re-creating it in Access and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried deleting the link and re-adding the table to no avail. I also entered the code using the function (without the hashes) and that didn't work either. Maybe something corrupted with those fields?

Comment: @mntyguy Aha, I see the syntax error. If you want to update multiple fields you need to use `SET Field1=value1, Field2=value2`, not `SET Field1=value1 AND Field2=value2`